# Does an R-based implementation of Fasano and Franceschini's (1987) 2D Kolmogorov-Smirnov test exist?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, bivariate

First I would like to recognize that similar versions of this question have been asked before, however these either did not pertain to Fasano and Franceschini's (1987) modification of the 2D KS test or were answered 5-10 years ago. As such, I believe this question may be useful myself and others interested in implementing this increasingly popular statistical tool in R, the most popular coding language used by freshwater ecologists.

I am looking to quantify a clear threshold-style relationship between the site-level density of a native, threatened trout species, and a highly invasive species that occupies a very similar niche. It appears to me and my advisor that a two-dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (specifically the version published by Fasano and Franceschini 1987 and popularized by Garvey et al. 1998) is the best way to do this (although I appreciate other suggestions), however to the best of my knowledge the only available implementations are coded in Python, C, Matlab, etc.

My question, simply put, is: does such an implementation exist in R? If not, what implementation would you recommend to someone with very little coding experience outside of R?

**Works cited:**
Fasano, Giovanni, and Alberto Franceschini. "A multidimensional version of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test." Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society 225.1 (1987): 155-170.

Garvey, James E., Elizabeth A. Marschall, and Russell A. Wright. "From star charts to stoneflies: detecting relationships in continuous bivariate data." Ecology 79.2 (1998): 442-447.

Comment: There is a package called `Peacock.test` which [says](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Peacock.test/Peacock.test.pdf) it implements the original definition of the two and three dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sampletest statistics given by Peacock  in 1983, avoiding the need for the Fasano and Franceschini 1987 variant